# In operator with one or More negative values not working with API Version 1.4 for Oracle Service Cloud

Tags: in-operator, rightnow-crm, negative-integer, roql

We have upgraded our application to use API version 1.4 and we observed the following error when ROQL query contains “in operator” with one or more negative values in the “in clause”. If all the values in the in clause are positive then this error is not occurring.

When we use API version 1.2, In clause with negative values is working fine without any exception. 
Is this intentional change in API version 1.4 or a regression introduced in version 1.4? Or we need to change the SOAP Request in some way?

The following is the ROQL query example.

```
USE operational; 
SELECT ovs2.ITABLE.ID, ovs2.ITABLE.INTEGERCOL FROM ovs2.ITABLE WHERE (ovs2$ITABLE.INTEGERCOL IN **(-2,4)**)
```

Exception received :

```
 WHERE clause contains mismatched data types in comparison
```

Comment: It does look like this might be a regression.  Since your `IN` list is small, switch to an `OR` clause instead and report the findings to customer care.

Comment: I gave the example IN with small list however our original application IN contains long list of values